# Run Play jobs on a custom threadpool

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I would like to run some jobs on a custom thread pool / executor service.

The reason is I have a lot of jobs that might overwhelm the normal job pool, so I want to separate them into a dedicated pool.

I tried creating a new ExecutorService and running jobs on it:

```
public static <T> F.Promise<T> runJobWithExecutor(ExecutorService executor, final Job<T> job) {
    final F.Promise<T> promise = new F.Promise<T>();
    executor.submit(new Callable<T>() {
        public T call() throws Exception {
            T result =  job.call();
            promise.invoke(result);
            return result;
        }
    });
    return promise;
}
```

but I'm getting various JPA errors:

> An SQLException was provoked by the following failure:
>   java.lang.InterruptedException [Cause: java.lang.InterruptedException
>   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method) at
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1315)
>   at
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
>   at
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
>   at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
>   at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:71)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
>   at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160) at
>   org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
>   at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:60) at
>   play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin.startTx(JPAPlugin.java:350) at
>   play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin.beforeInvocation(JPAPlugin.java:318) at
>   play.plugins.PluginCollection.beforeInvocation(PluginCollection.java:428)
>   at play.Invoker$Invocation.before(Invoker.java:217) at
>   play.jobs.Job.call(Job.java:139) at
>   org.commercesciences.play.Jobs3$1.call(Jobs3.java:16) at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Is there anything more I need to do in order to run jobs on separate threads?

I'm using play 1.2.4-mbknor-3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things that relate to the context of your question (even if not a direct response to it).

1).
Try changing the max queue size.

```
int maxThreads = 50;
int queueSize = 1000; // should be big enough!
ExecutorService newExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(maxThreads, maxThreads, Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(queueSize, true));
```

2).
Also, in terms of performance, if you don't need Hibernate, consider Callable instead of Job - play!'s Job is very heavy by nature , it initializes Hibernate and other plugins if needed, per Job.